# How do I prove that the sets x = {y}, y = {z} and z = {x} can’t exist with the axiom of regulation/foundation in ZFC?

Tags: set-theory

How do I prove that the sets $x = \{y\}, y = \{z\} \text{ and } z =\{x\}$ can’t exist with the axiom of regulation/foundation in ZFC?

I’m having the damnest time trying to prove this since the sets are not assumed to be transitive sets.

I’ve tried using powersets and union operations but these have brought me no luck thus far.
I’m beginning to wonder whether or not this is possible to prove.

Comment: Take a look at $A = \{ x,y,z\}$.

Comment: Why do I feel that this was asked recently?